# How to make the popup displayed on the center of screen in mudsimpletable in mudblazor c#

Tags: c#, popup, mudblazor

I am using mudsimpletable and in each row there is a button on clicking it, I want to open a popup , but instead of opening near the button it opens on far top. How to rectify this.

This is my sample code.

```
 <MudSimpleTable Style="overflow-x: auto;">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 @foreach (var h in headings)
 {
 <th>@h</th>
 }
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 @foreach (var row in rows)
 {       
  <tr>
  @foreach (var x in row.Split())
  {
  <td>@x
  <MudIconButton  OnClick="()=>ToggleOpen(x)" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Fullscreen" Color="@Color.Primary" ToggledIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FullscreenExit" ToggledColor="@Color.Secondary" />
  </td>
  }
  </tr>
  }
 </tbody>
 </MudSimpleTable>
 <MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" Fixed="true" Class="px-4 pt-4" >
 <div class="d-flex flex-column">
 <MudText>@canonicalvalue</MudText>
 <MudButton OnClick="ToggleOpen" Class="ml-auto mr-n3 mb-1" Color="Color.Error">Close</MudButton>
 </div>
 </MudPopover>
```

This is code snippet:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmoaxYrGrhWiLKQ

I don't know how to make every popup display near the button being clicked.Is there any in-built way or workaround.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `MudPopOver` has options to align the position of the modal and also the text alignment inside it. You can use the `AnchorOrigin` and `TransformOrigin` attributes in your `MudPopOver` options to achieve your requirement:

```
<MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" Fixed="true" Class="px-4 pt-4" AnchorOrigin="Origin.CenterCenter" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter" >
```

You can refer more on these options in the [docs](https://mudblazor.com/components/popover#direction-and-location)

Comment: I have tried this before but it appears at center of the table but i want the popup to be displayed next to the button based on which button is click

Answer (score 1):

The `MudPopOver` attributes `AnchorOrigin` and `TransformOrigin` sets the component in relation to its parent. In case of your snippet it's the page itself.

Therefore The Popover has to be part of the table cell. Like this

```
@foreach (var x in row.Split())
{
    <td>
        @x
        <MudIconButton  OnClick="()=>ToggleOpen(x)" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Fullscreen" Color="@Color.Primary" ToggledIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FullscreenExit" ToggledColor="@Color.Secondary" />
        <MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" Fixed="true" Class="px-4 pt-4" >
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <MudText>@canonicalvalue</MudText>
                <MudButton OnClick="ToggleOpen" Class="ml-auto mr-n3 mb-1" Color="Color.Error">Close</MudButton>
            </div>
        </MudPopover> 
    </td>
}
```

**Be aware** You need an `open state` for each of these or you would open and close each one simultaneously.

So you would have to use indeces in each foreach loop. Which would look something like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var row in rows.Select((value, i) => new {value, i}))
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cell in row.value.Split().Select((value, j) => new {value, j}))
            {
                <td>@cell.value
                    <MudIconButton  OnClick="()=>ToggleOpen(cell.value, cell.j + row.i * row.value.Split().Count())" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Fullscreen" Color="@Color.Primary" ToggledIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.FullscreenExit" ToggledColor="@Color.Secondary" />
                        <MudPopover 
                            Open="@isOpen[cell.j + row.i * row.value.Split().Count()]" 
                            Fixed="true" Class="px-4 pt-4" 
                            AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" 
                            TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter"
                        >
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                <MudText>@canonicalvalue</MudText>
                                <MudButton OnClick="@(() => ToggleOpen())" Class="ml-auto mr-n3 mb-1" Color="Color.Error">Close</MudButton>
                            </div>
                        </MudPopover>
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

and

```
bool[] isOpen = 
{false, false, false, false, false, false,
false, false, false, false, false, false,
false, false, false, false, false, false,
false, false, false, false, false, false,
false, false, false, false, false, false,
false, false, false, false, false, false
};
```

With `isOpen.Length = rows * columns`

[MudSnippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYQeYdEBIYFBjPJK)